# Use a delay of one second to nest another animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently using a timeout, but I want to use a delay. When I pass a second of the first animation I want the other to start and that is a linear animation. How can I detect when each animation ends?

http://jsfiddle.net/ohtkmes8/4/

```
$('#coolDiv2').css({
  left: $('#container').width() - $('#coolDiv').width()
});
$("#coolDiv").css({
  left: $('#container').width() - ($('#coolDiv').width() + $('#coolDiv2').width())
}).animate({"left":"0px"}, 9000);
setTimeout(function(){
  $('#coolDiv2').animate({"left":"50px"}, 9000);
}, 1000);

<div id="container">
  <div id="coolDiv">cool</div>
  <div id="coolDiv2">other text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/using-jquery-to-detect-when-css3-animations-and-transitions-end

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's [`animate`](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) method accepts a callback argument to be called when the animation is completed:

```
$("#coolDiv").css({
  left: $('#container').width() - ($('#coolDiv').width() + $('#coolDiv2').width())
}).animate({"left":"0px"}, 9000, function() {
   $('#coolDiv2').animate({"left":"50px"}, 9000);
});
```

Comment: great, I need it when the first animation starts (delay 1), after a second starts the other one.